# Media Manager 504 error

Tags: joomla-3.x, media-manager

I am working on a website where media manager data is quite huge. Because of this reason the media manager is not working and gives

> 504 Gateway timeout error

- Total media manager files are of 25gb.
- Server timeout has been set to 120 seconds.
- Joomla Version - 3.6.5

Is there any way by which this can be resolved? Or is there any limit defined that how much files media manager can hold upto ?

Comment: Have you put a support ticket in with your hosting?  Many times a 504 is triggered by the hosting company after you violate some internal policy/quota for use.

Comment: I have already checked with my hosting and the server timeout has been increased after my request to 120 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to set the `timeout` value to `500`. Though it is quite huge but the since the data was of 25GB , this much value was needed.